# Apply multiple conditions and apply function to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to be able to add a new column to a data frame and then use conditions about the values in each row to categorise it into zero, one or multiple categories which would be record in the final column.

e.g., with this DataFrame, df

```
     Name  Height Qualification   Type
0     Jai     5.1           Msc     []
1  Princi     6.2            MA     []
2  Gaurav     5.1           Msc     []
3    Anuj     5.2           Msc     []
```

I would like to be able to list multiple category types in the final column based on what is in the rest of the DataFrame.

e.g.,

```
Type A - Height < 6 and Qualification == Msc
Type B - Height < 5.2
```

So the result would be

```
     Name  Height Qualification   Type
0     Jai     5.1           Msc     ["A", "B"]
1  Princi     6.2            MA     []
2  Gaurav     5.1           Msc     ["A", "B"]
3    Anuj     5.2           Msc     ["A"]
```

I can use np.select or np.where to do a single category, but can't figure out a nice way to do this with multiple possible categories.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function and apply it to your dataframe while creating your `Type` column :

```py
def get_type(row):
    out = []
    if row.Height < 6 and row.Qualification == "Msc":
        out.append("A")
    if row.Height < 5.2:
        out.append("B")
    return out

df["Type"] = df.apply(get_type, axis=1)
```